# Check if a PHP cookie exists not worked

Tags: php, wordpress, function, cookies, isset

I am using this code to set a `cookie` in **Wordpress**

**functions.php**

```
function wp_test_req($post_id) { 
    if(isset($_POST['submits'])) {
        setcookie( 'mycookie', 'value', time()+ 36, '/');
    }
} 
add_action('init', 'wp_test_req');
```

**HTML**

and with this code then see if cookie exists

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <?php 
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']))
    { echo '<input type="submit" value="Up+1" id="submit" name="submits">';}
    else { echo 'NotSet';}
  ?>
</form>
```

problem is `if (!isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']))` not work.

In fact, the problem is that nothing happens in the first click, but changes are made in the second click

Where is wrong?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

force $_COOKIE['mycookie'] for affect immediatly

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['submits'])) {
    setcookie('mycookie', 'value', time()+ 36);
    $_COOKIE['mycookie'] = 'value'; // <----
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
  <?php
    if (empty($_COOKIE['mycookie'])) {
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Up+1" id="submit" name="submits">';
    } else {
        echo 'NotSet';
    }
  ?>
</form>
```